# Gradient Descent Linear Regression in Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, linear-regression

This a bit of a long shot, but I wonder if someone could look at this. Am I doing Batch Gradient descent for linear regression correctly here?
It gives the expected answers for a single independent and intercept, but not for multiple independent variables.

```
/**
 * (using Colt Matrix library)
 * @param alpha Learning Rate
 * @param thetas Current Thetas
 * @param independent 
 * @param dependent
 * @return new Thetas
 */
public DoubleMatrix1D descent(double         alpha,
                              DoubleMatrix1D thetas,
                              DoubleMatrix2D independent,
                              DoubleMatrix1D dependent ) {
    Algebra algebra     = new Algebra();

    // ALPHA*(1/M) in one.
    double  modifier    = alpha / (double)independent.rows();

    //I think this can just skip the transpose of theta.
    //This is the result of every Xi run through the theta (hypothesis fn)
    //So each Xj feature is multiplied by its Theata, to get the results of the hypothesis
    DoubleMatrix1D hypothesies = algebra.mult( independent, thetas );

    //hypothesis - Y  
    //Now we have for each Xi, the difference between predictect by the hypothesis and the actual Yi
    hypothesies.assign(dependent, Functions.minus);

    //Transpose Examples(MxN) to NxM so we can matrix multiply by hypothesis Nx1
    DoubleMatrix2D transposed = algebra.transpose(independent);

    DoubleMatrix1D deltas     = algebra.mult(transposed, hypothesies );


    // Scale the deltas by 1/m and learning rate alhpa.  (alpha/m)
    deltas.assign(Functions.mult(modifier));

    //Theta = Theta - Deltas
    thetas.assign( deltas, Functions.minus );

    return( thetas );
}
```

Comment: As for the algorithm steps and the math, I cannot see anything wrong. I am not familiar with `Colt` library but I assume the function names are expressive and the meaning is clear. I assume you have the first column of the `independent` matrix a vector of ones to estimate the intercept. How the values are different in case of `multiple regression`?

Comment: First column is 1's for intercept. I think it may be correct, and I'm experiencing colinearity in my test data. I created test data such that I had x1, and x2, and x2 was just 2*x1. I set my dependent variable to be y= .5*x1 + (1/3)*x2. It converged, but not to what I would expect.

Comment: For example in the above case, I get Thetas of .6333(x1) and .2666(x2). It does correctly pick out whatever intercept I put in to the function.. (for example y= .5*x1 + (1/3)*x2 + 10). If I use WEKA on the same dataset it handles colinearity automatically and just does  1.1666 * x1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your implementation and based on your comment the problem in `collinearity` which you induce when generating `x2`. This is problematic in regression estimation.

To test your algorithm, you can generate two independent columns of random numbers. Pick a value of `w0`, `w1` and `w2` i.e. coefficients for `intercept`, `x1` and `x2` respectively. Calculate the dependent value `y`.

Then see if your stochastic/batch gradient decent algorithm can recover `w0`, `w1` and `w2` values

Answer (score 0):

I think adding

```
  // ALPHA*(1/M) in one.
double  modifier    = alpha / (double)independent.rows();
```

Is a bad Idea, since you're mixing gradient function with the gradient descent algorithm, it's much better to have a gradientDescent algorithm inside a public method like following in Java:

```
import org.la4j.Matrix;
import org.la4j.Vector;

public Vector gradientDescent(Matrix x, Matrix y, int kmax, double alpha)
{
    int k=1;
    Vector  thetas = Vector.fromArray(new double[] { 0.0, 0.0});
    while (k<kmax)
    {
        thetas = thetas.subtract(gradient(x, y, thetas).multiply(alpha));
        k++;
    }
    return thetas;
}
```