# Testing Logistic Regression. Doesn't converge using 1 or 0, but does using logit

Tags: java, machine-learning, regression

I have created a simple Logistic Regression using gradient descent using my linear regression code from here:
[Gradient Descent Linear Regression in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948503/gradient-descent-linear-regression-in-java)

Now I'm simply adapting it for Logistic Regression by changing the hypothesis by adding the logit transform: 1/(1+e^(-z)), where z is the original Theta^T * X. And not scaling by the population size.

When trying to test my results I get a confusing behavior: I set the independent variables(X) to a random number * an expected weight and the dependent(Y) to the logit of their sum, So y= logit(w0*1 + w1*x1 + w2*x2).

Now in this case it converges to the correct answer, and I can recover the expected weights. But obviously I should have Y as 0 or 1. But when I round up or down, I no longer converge.

Here I am generating training data:

```
@Test
public void testLogisticDescentMultiple() {
    //...

    //initialize Independent Xi
    //Going to create test data y= 10 + .5(x1) + .33(x2) 
    for( int x=0;x<NUM_EXAMPLES;x++) {
        independent.set(x, 0, 1); //x0 We always set this to 1 for the intercept
        independent.set(x, 1, random.nextGaussian()); //x1
        independent.set(x, 2, random.nextGaussian() ); //x2
    }

    //initialize dependent Yi
    for( int x=0;x<NUM_EXAMPLES;x++) {
        double val      = w0 +  (w1*independent.get(x,1)) + (w2*independent.get(x,2));
        double logitVal = logit( val );

        //Converges without this code block
        if( logitVal < 0.5 ) {
            logitVal = 0;
        }else {
            logitVal = 1;
        }
        //

        dependent.set(x, logitVal );
    }
    //...
}

public static double logit( double val ) {
    return( 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-val)));
}

//updated Logistic Regression
public DoubleMatrix1D logisticDescent(double         alpha,
                                      DoubleMatrix1D thetas,
                                      DoubleMatrix2D independent,
                                      DoubleMatrix1D dependent ) {
    Algebra algebra     = new Algebra();

    //hypothesis is 1/( 1+ e ^ -(theta(Transposed) * X))
    //start with theata(Transposed)*X
    DoubleMatrix1D hypothesies = algebra.mult( independent, thetas );

    //h = 1/(1+ e^-h)
    hypothesies.assign(new DoubleFunction() {
        @Override
        public double apply (double val) {
            return( logit( val ) );
        }
    });

    //hypothesis - Y
    //Now we have for each Xi, the difference between predicted by the hypothesis and the actual Yi
    hypothesies.assign(dependent, Functions.minus);

    //Transpose Examples(MxN) to NxM so we can matrix multiply by hypothesis Nx1
    DoubleMatrix2D transposed = algebra.transpose(independent);

    DoubleMatrix1D deltas     = algebra.mult(transposed, hypothesies );

    // thetas = thetas - (deltas*alpha)  in one step
    thetas.assign(deltas, Functions.minusMult(alpha));

    return( thetas );
}
```

Comment: I used a sample dataset from the Coursera Machine Learning Course and this did converge. So I guess it's just not valid to generate test data the way I did.

Comment: Using Weka to do logistic regression on the coursera dataset, I get the same answer, except the signs are flipped on all of the parameters.. Not sure about that. Anyways, closing question.